# List of Valid DocuSign Merge Fields for Branding Emails? #DocuSignAPI

Tags: docusignapi

Trying to determine how to create custom DocuSign merge fields for branding emails using the branding feature and the API.  Also looking for a list of possible fields.  There is a bunch of documentation about how to perform the customization but no details about the valid merge fields.  I have tried contacting DocuSign directly but they were unable to provide the details so I thought maybe someone in the community has gone through this process.

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: I wish there was a simple answer for this, but there really isn't. Each email template will have access to specific information. Example: EnvelopeActivation will have a [[RecipientName]], but not all templates have to do with a recipient. My best advise is trial and error to see what's available in each template, that will match your needs.

Comment: That's the problem there is no way to actually do trial and error because there is no list of specific field names.  The main task we are trying to accomplish was to pull either custom envelope fields or some tabs from a document in the envelope to put within the email notifications, but at the moment we seem to be limited to using the EmailBlurb functionality that is part of the API.  If you have any other ideas that would be great.

Comment: I agree with Andrew that you really would need to test since not all merge fields are applicable to each type of email template. I can include a snapshot to help get you started: AccountName, AssignNotaryURL, DeclineReason, DeclinerName, DigitalCertificateIssuer, DigitalCertificateIssuerLink, DocumentCode, DocumentNames, DocuSignAppEmailPath, DocuSignAppImg, EmailBlurb, EnvelopeExpirationDate, EnvelopeID, Error, FailedRecipientName, FaxId, ForgotPasswordQuestion1, ForgotPasswordQuestion2, ForgotPasswordQuestion3, ForgotPasswordQuestion4, GmailPreviewPaneButtonName, Information, NewEmail

Comment: Some more: NewRecipientName, NotaryAddress, NotaryEmail, NotaryLoginURL, NotaryName, NotaryPhone, 
OriginalRecipientName, PoweredByImg, PresetPath, PreviewURL, ProductName, PromoContent, PurgeDate, QuickURL
RecipientAccessCode, RecipientDeliveredDateTime, RecipientDeliveryFailedDateTime, RecipientDeliveryFailedReason, RecipientEmail, RecipientName, RecipientNote, ReservedDomainEmail, SenderCompany, SenderEmail, SenderName, 
SenderThumbnailImage, SignerAddress, SignerEmail, SignerName, SignerPhone, Subject, SubjectInput, 
SupportEmail, SupportName, TemplateType, TimeZone, VoidReason