# DocuSign In-Session Landing Pages & URL Redirect Parameters

Tags: docusignapi

I'm looking for the descriptions of the parameters that are automatically returned in redirectURLs if they are configured for brands or in-session landing pages.

I've noticed the following

- env
- pf
- r

I also would like to know what shortcut commands there are so that when I'm creating templates or redirectURLs I can embed DocuSign related data.
Example: [Signer1_UserName] in the Subject of an email

Comment: Are you referring to the DocuSign Signature API? What do you mean by an in-session landing page? For embeddedRecipent, Sender and other views, the redirect includes the event query parameter. Where are you seeing env, pf, r??

Comment: I also have no idea where you are seeing these 3 values from, please provide relevant documentation and/or much more info to your question.

Answer (score 1):

This is a long time past but thought it may help others with the same question....

These parameters get appended when a PowerForm was used to create the envelope.

The values in these parameters are:

- env - The ID of the Envelope that was created.
- pf - The ID of the PowerForm that was used.
- r - The ID of the recipient who signed.

The values could be used in subsequent processing using the API or when dealing with messages from DocuSign Connect.

One example:  Since all PowerForms share a single set of in-session landing page URLs, your landing page can use the `pf` value to determine what page to display or redirect to next.

Regarding merge codes, DocuSign does publish a list but this SO question may help you:  [List of Valid DocuSign Merge Fields for Branding Emails? #DocuSignAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30740728/list-of-valid-docusign-merge-fields-for-branding-emails-docusignapi)